# How to make a INPUT as part of source code in Python 3?

Tags: if-statement, input

I would like to know how to use a input as a part of source code

for example, the source code looks like below

```
        data[80]='a'
        ...

        ...
        t=input("blabla")
        if(t):
            dosomething()
```

then when we input a string like

`data[80]=='a'`

then the `dosomething()` occurs.

How can I make this happen?

Comment: What programming language are you working in? Is `input` a built-in function, a library you are using, a function you've written or something completely hypothetical?

Comment: I am using python 3 , I didnot mention it sorry. so it is built-in function

Comment: Look for my comment. I've updated it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To execute string as a code with mixed with your own code you can use function eval:

```
data = {}
data[80] = 'a'
t = input('please input code') #if you input here data[80]=='a' program outputs Hello world
if eval(t):
    print("Hello World")
```

This code will print `Hello world` if you input `data[80]=='a'`

Comment: Thank you very much for your kind answer :)

Comment: I did, I'am new to stack overflow, I couldn;t find the right answer from the google. You gave me a great answer and I marked this. Thanks! Have a great day!